# Retrieval of columns from functions that returns table (or setof record)

Tags: postgresql

All time I have an variation of this problem, and not remember how to workaround, only "oop was so simple, but how to?"... Perhaps there are some patterns and best way to work with each pattern.  Let's see the main one, examplefying by `unnest()` and `ts_stat()`.

First, good examples, no problems, because `unnest()`  returns only one column:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(array[1,2,3]) t(id); -- is ok, the int columns there!
SELECT unnest(array[1,2,3]) t(id); -- is ok, the int columns

WITH t AS (SELECT unnest(array[1,2,3]) as id)
 SELECT id, unnest(array[4,id]) as x
 FROM t;  -- more complex, but ok!
```

Now a function that returns a defined *SETOF RECORD*,

```
SELECT * FROM ts_stat('SELECT kx FROM terms where id=2') -- GOOD
-- show all word|ndoc|nentry columns

SELECT ts_stat('SELECT kx FROM terms where id=2') as x -- BAD
-- because lost columns, show only "x" column... but works

-- NOTE: you can imagine any other function, as json_each(), etc.
```

See GOOD/BAD considerations... So, **this is the problem**: a SETOF RECORD with more tham one column. In the simplest (`unnest` above) case, the solution is to use in the "FROM side", as a table; but, when RECORD have multiple fields, arises the problem.

```
--MAIN EXAMPLE FOR THE DISCUSSION:
WITH t AS (SELECT unnest(array[1,2,3]) as id)
 SELECT id, ts_stat('SELECT kx FROM terms where id='||id) as x
 FROM t;  -- BAD, but works...
```

Now, in this main example, is not possible to use `ts_stat()` in the "FROM side", so, characterizing **the pattern**: *a function that returns a TABLE or a SETOF RECORD, in a query where we need columns, but the function can't in the "FROM side"*.

QUESTION: What the generic (and most elegant) solution to this *pattern*? How (syntax pattern) to show columns?

---

NOTE: another problem is that, if you not remember exactly the syntax of solution, you try things that not works... In this case an error:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT unnest(array[1,2,3]) as id)
 SELECT id, x.word, x.ndoc, x.nentry 
 FROM (
      SELECT t.nsid, 
             ts_stat('SELECT kx FROM terms where id='||id) as x
      FROM t
  ) s;
```

SQL PARSER ERROR (PostgreSQL 9.5): *no table "x" in the FROM clause*.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** use a [set-returning-function (SRF)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) in a `SELECT` list. The main example should be written with an implicit `LATERAL JOIN`:

```
SELECT v.id, x.*
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) v(id)
JOIN ts_stat('SELECT kx FROM terms where id=' || v.id) x ON true;
```

The [lateral join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) is implicit here because an SRF can refer to columns from relations specified before it the `FROM` clause without using the keyword `LATERAL`. In the example above the SRF `ts_stat()` makes a lateral reference to column and relation `v(id)`. You can also do this with e.g. sub-queries but then you have to explicitly use the keyword `LATERAL`.

Note that while you can use a SRF in a select list, its use is discouraged. You provide the example of `unnest(anyarray)` which is interesting because there is also the overloaded variant `unnest(anyarray, ...)` (i.e. unnest multiple arrays in one call) which will throw an error when used in a select list; in can only be used as a row source. The reason why you should not use SRFs in a select list is that there is no obvious solution when using multiple SRFs each producing a different number of rows.

Comment: Good (!), this is the "solution pattern". And "never use a set-returning-function in a SELECT list" is a good rule. The self-evident and ideal solution, for pg9+, is the `LATERAL JOIN`, can you show an example? (translate the same query to a lateral join query)

Comment: The example in the answer already is an implicit lateral join. See updated answer for some more explanation.

Comment: Oops, sorry, the correct text of this commented question is *"can you show and EXPLICIT example?"*, using  the LATERAL clause

Comment: ... And about my [NOTE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36065650/287948), the PARSER ERROR, it seems for you a parser BUG?

Comment: Come on, Peter. I added links to the relevant documentation and elaborated on lateral joins. A little self-help here would go a long way. If you have a *specific* question related to this post *after* going over the docs, then I will most gladly help, but SO is not a [school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).

Comment: And with regards to the parser error: using an alias for a SRF in a select list does not make this alias a row source. In the main query only `s` is know because that is what you called the sub-query; the `x` alias from the sub-query is a *field* in the main query, not a row source.

Comment: Ooops gain,  sorry again, not read the link, perfect link (!), I never see before [this Guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html)!  All my long question-text is about it, the need of better documentation for *table functions* (the *need of a school about it*). Hum.. understand why not read before: I read the guide years ago, and this guide came only recent years, with pg9.X.